# Get String of n:1 Domain Model Object

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x

I made an extension for typo3 with the extension builder. In there I have a relation called "sex" that refers to another model object from type n:1 (of course, everyone can only just have one sex). Now I want to present that in a table. When I use `{person.sex}` I can just see the path to the model object and the selection as a number. Is there a way to get a string out of it so that it says 'male' or 'female'?

Comment: So sex is a model? Does it have properties? Like a name or a title?

Comment: sex is a model, yes, and it has a property also named sex as a string

Comment: So to resolve the value of sex you have to use person.sex.sex. Or otherwise you adjust the getter in Person.getSex()

Comment: ok, thanks, i tried to use the name of the object model, but not just the property...looked a little bit too easy  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *sex* is your model that has the property *sex* (type string) you can use {person.sex.sex} in TYPO3 Fluid.

An alternative approach is to adjust the getter method `Person.getSex()` in your model *person* so that it returns the property *sex* from the model *sex*:

```
getSex() {
    return $this->sex->getSex();
}
```

Having a look at the provided pseudo code you should think about the naming of the properties ;)

Another tip: you can use {person.sex} in TYPO3 Fluid. That helps to know which properties are available in the template object.